# php-on-couch get all records fast

Tags: php, json, couchdb

With PHP-ON-COUCH, i try to get all records in couchdb with php-on-couch, but it's not works fastly.

```
 require_once "lib/couch.php";
 require_once "lib/couchClient.php";
 require_once "lib/couchDocument.php";    

 $couch_dsn = "http://localhost:5984/";
 $couch_db  = "couch";

  $client = new couchClient($couch_dsn,$couch_db);
  $all_singers = $client->getAllDocs();
  foreach ( $all_singers->rows as $row ) {
    $doc = $client->getDoc($id);
    echo $doc->singer;
    echo $doc->title;
    echo $doc->description;
   }
```

Is there another method to do this properly?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the functions correctly. What you're doing right now is extremly slow because your fetching all the docs then you fetch them again 1 by one with the (getDoc) function. When you query all docs, you get something like this:

```
{
    "total_rows": 0,
    "count": 0,
    "rows": [{
        "key": 1,
        "value": "value",
        "doc": {
            "singer": "Foo",
            "title": "bar"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here's a revised version of your code :

```
<?php

require_once "lib/couch.php";
require_once "lib/couchClient.php";
require_once "lib/couchDocument.php";

$couch_dsn = "http://localhost:5984/";
$couch_db = "couch";

$client = new couchClient($couch_dsn, $couch_db);
$all_singers = null;

try {
    $all_singers = $client->include_docs(true)->getAllDocs();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Handle the exception here.
}
if (!isset($all_singers) || !isset($all_singers->rows))
    echo "No singers found";
else
    foreach ($all_singers->rows as $row) {
        if (isset($row->error))
            continue; //Log the error or something like this
        if (isset($row->doc)) {
            $doc = $row->doc;
            echo $doc->singer;
            echo $doc->title;
            echo $doc->description;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, It's works fine!  You have just to add the parameter "include_docs" in method getAllDocs of class couchClient

Comment: I changed it, please accept the answer if it helped you! :)